# Typescript intersection type cast to one of the types that makes the intersection

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm hoping someone can help me find a clean way to do this.

I have two interfaces like this

```
interface A {
  prop1: string
  prop2: string
}

interface B {
  prop2: string
  prop3: string
}
```

And an intersection like so

```
myIntersection: A & B
```

I'm wanting to be able to cast this intersection type to either A or B depending on a condition

```
let whatIWant: any = {}
if(myCondition)
  whatIWant = myIntersection as A
else
  whatIWant = myIntersection as B
```

When I do it this way, there aren't any errors but the new object still contains all of the properties from the intersection object.  Is there a clean and simple way to do this?

The problem that this is causing for me is that i'm wanting to save the whatIWant object as metadata on an image so I need to strip all of the properties that arent on the type i'm trying to cast to.

Comment: Casting to a type just changes what information the compiler knows about the object, it doesn't actually change the object itself (and since you've defined `whatIWant` as `any`, the compiler still doesn't know anything about it anyway). What problem is this causing for you? There might be another solution but it depends on what you actually need.

Comment: Thanks for the comment John. I see what you mean.  The problem that this is causing for me is that i'm wanting to save the `whatIWant` object as metadata on an image so I need to strip all of the properties that arent on the type i'm trying to cast to.  I'm beginning to think maybe I can use classes instead of interfaces and use copy constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using classes instead of interfaces should do what you want. Interfaces only describe what properties an object has, not what it doesn't have, so the easiest way would be to copy the properties you need to a new object. Without knowing more about your actual structure, I might do something like this:

```
// replace myIntersection with a base interface
interface MyData {
    prop1: string
    prop2: string
    prop3: string
}

// turn A and B into classes with constructors that take a MyData object
class A {
    prop1: string
    prop2: string
    constructor (data: MyData) {
        this.prop1 = data.prop1
        this.prop2 = data.prop2
    }
}
class B {
    prop2: string
    prop3: string
    constructor (data: MyData) {
        this.prop2 = data.prop2
        this.prop3 = data.prop3
    }
}

// Then initialize a new object based on your condition
const whatIWant = myCondition ? new A(myDataObject) : new B(myDataObject)
```

Comment: This is very similar to the solution I just came up with.  I'll look into this to determine if it is better to have an interface that replaces the intersection.  Thank you for taking the time to answer it!

Comment: @abaga129 It should work either way, I think. This way felt cleaner to me, but functionally there shouldn't be any difference (unless something in your actual code handles it differently), so go ahead and use whichever way you like better.

Answer (score 0):

Well I've found an alternative way to do this.  I'm not going to mark this as the accepted answer since there may be a better way to do this.  I've opted to use classes instead of interfaces and use copy constructors to create new objects from the intersection type.

Example

```
class A {
    prop1: string
    prop2: string
    constructor(obj: A)
    {
        this.prop1 = obj.prop1
        this.prop2 = obj.prop2
    }
}

class B {
    prop2: string
    prop3: string
    constructor(obj: B)
    {
        this.prop2 = obj.prop2
        this.prop3 = obj.prop3
    }
}

myIntersection: A & B

let whatIWant: any = {}
if(myCondition)
  whatIWant = new A(myIntersection)
else
  whatIWant = new B(myIntersection)
```

This works for my purposes. I was just hoping for a cleaner way to do this